# Python - Convert Underscore to Fullstop

Tags: python, coding-style

Convert String `'321_1'` to `'321.1'`.

I would like to create a method to convert the underscore to full stop. i used split but it cant work .. Anyone can help me? or must i use while loop

Convert underscore to fullstop

```
def Convert_toFullStop(text):

    x1 = ""
    words = text.split()
    if words in ("_"):
        words = "."
    print words
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do

```
def Convert_toFullStop(text):
    return text.replace('_', '.')
```

and leave the `print` to the caller.

Answer (score 7):

use the [replace()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) function?

```
newtext = text.replace('_','.')
```

Comment: python is like spoken language. Try it before you ask next time :-)

Comment: @user2837162 Not a function exactly, it's a method of string objects.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to use `replace()` method as it's suggested in the answers above.

But if you really want to use `split()`:

```
words = text.split("_")
print ".".join(words)
```

By default `split()` method splits by space character.